# HTML5 drag & drop: The dragged element content is missing in Webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, webkit

I'm trying to implement something similar to a cart where you can drop items from a list.
This items (`<li>` elements) has some elements inside (divs, span, and that stuff).
The drag and drop itself works great. But the dragged element's image doesn't show its content in Webkit browsers.

My list element has a border an a background color. In Firefox, the image is the whole item. In Webkit browsers, only the dragged element without content. I see the background and border, but without text inside.

I tried to make a copy of the element and force it to be the image, but doesn't work.

```
var dt = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
dt.setDragImage( $(ev.target).clone()[0], 0, 0);
```

I have a simplified example that exhibit the same behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/ksnJf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [addElement](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-datatransfer-addelement):

```
dt.addElement(this);
```

instead in the *dragstart* event. But beware transparent background :)

BTW, why would you don't use code from [example 1](http://html5demos.com/drag) or even [example 2](http://html5demos.com/drag-anything)?

UPD:
For Webkit need to use [webkitUserDrag](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbixvwm.php) property or equivalent CSS

```
-webkit-user-drag: element; 
-webkit-user-select:none;
```

There is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/lex_rwx/XMCta/) of copying LI elements from UL to DIV.

Comment: Using dt.addElement(this) i get that error: Object #<a Clipboard> has no method 'addElement'. 
I used a different approach than html5 demos because i really hate writting JS without jQuery. But for testing i changed the example to use h5utils.js and the addEvent function, with identical result. I only see the border and background, but no content. 
I'll go diner now, and the i will edit the html5 demo, adding divs and span inside the dragged element, to see it it works on the demo.

Comment: Look at example of drag and copy.

Answer (score 1):

I've just test it. It works! But all code in the JS, i have tested in any way or another, and didn't work for me. And then, I saw the difference. The  used as a wrapper do the magic.
This works

```
<li draggable="true" class="course" data-id="1">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="name">Agua Mineral</div>
      <div class="price">1.50</div>€
    </div>
</li>
```

This doesn't

```
<li draggable="true" class="course" data-id="1">
      <div class="name">Agua Mineral</div>
      <div class="price">1.50</div>€
</li>
```

I don't know if its a bug or its intentional, but anyway it's inconsistent in different browsers. I'll ask on webkit group.

Thanks!

Comment: I have some news. I've realized the REAL problem. Webkit doesn't show any float content inside dragged element. So, finally, changed float divs to inline-block, and all works fine.